# How can I add sub1.sub2.example.com to my GoDaddy hosting account?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, subdomain, godaddy

I'm using GoDaddy's Ultimate hosting plan, and I'd like to know how to add `sub.sub domain` to it.

For example, I want to create a site as `es.n.example.com`. However, GoDaddy tells me when I add the dot that it cannot be added because of forbidden characters, saying: `Your Subdomain name(s) can only contain letters, numbers, and dashes`.

But I've already created it in the "DNS Zone Editor" and it successfully accepted it.

As a test I forwarded that `sub1.sub2.example.com` to my IP-address with a local web server I have installed in my computer and it ran just fine. I was able to access the domain `sub1.sub2` as a vhost on Apache.

Is there a way to do this in my GoDaddy hosting account?

Comment: Can you add screen shots of what you are seeing?

Comment: @Detallado If you're using their old control panel, you likely won't be able to add multi-level subdomains like this (i.e., via "Hosted Domains"). You might try to upgrade your hosting account to cPanel, which is what they're using now, and will give you added options. You can always contact their hosting support department too to see if they can help.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `CNAME` with dot notation in it.  So you can create a `CNAME` which is `es.n` and point it to the a record and it will take care of what you want.   This is done via GoDaddy DNS hosting (free usually with all domains)

Comment: This works so perfectly, thank you Frank. Tested with Godaddy and Zone Edit.

Answer (score 1):

## "**How to set up a sub subdomain**"

Edited from [*Tech Titbits*](https://techtitbits.com/2008/07/how-to-set-up-a-sub-subdomain/),
Jul 8th, 2008 by Ellimist.

> I’ve been getting quite a few hits from Google to the DNS Guide post
>   from people searching for how to set up a sub subdomain.
>
> It’s quite simple actually. Say you want to set up a sub sub domain
>   sub2.sub1.example.com. All you need to do is create an A record for
>   sub2.sub1.example.com and point it to the required IP(the IP of the
>   server hosting the sub sub domain). If you want
>   www.sub2.sub1.example.com to work(not required in most cases), you
>   should create another A record for www.sub2.sub1.example.com and point
>   it to the same IP. This can also be done using a CNAME record.
>
> So, if the server that is going to host your sub sub domain has IP
>   192.0.2.4, your DNS records should be like this :
>
> ```
> sub2.sub1.example.com.       A     192.0.2.4
> www.sub2.sub1.example.com.   A     192.0.2.4
> ```
>
> If you want to use CNAME records :
>
> ```
> sub2.sub1.example.com.       A       192.0.2.4
> www.sub2.sub1.example.com.   CNAME   sub2.sub1.example.com.
> ```
>
> There may be a lot of reasons why someone would want to use a sub sub
>   domain; the most important of them being forming meaningful(or
>   desired) words/phrases out of a domain name. One of the most popular
>   example of a site on a sub sub domain is www.Del.icio.us. It clearly
>   illustrates the usefulness of a sub sub domain.

Comment: It is wrong to use `domain.com` and `1.2.3.4` as examples and it is a pity that you reverted my edit about it. Please read RFC 2606 and 5737!

Comment: @PatrickMevzek No worries, brought it back and mentioned it has been edited from the original.